# Octave doesn't plot from external file

Tags: plot, octave

If I type *octave* on terminal and then:

```
x = linspace(0, 2*pi, 100);
y = sin(x);
plot(x, y);
```

the graphic correctly shows the plot.
That's what I tried: I created a text file named *gettingStarted.m* where I wrote the three lines above inside of it, in order to execute this file with Octave.
I type *octave gettingStarted.m* but the plot doesn't appear.
Does not plotting work if you run an external file with Octave?

I'm working on Ubuntu 12.04, 32 bit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are running an Octave script that includes a plotting command, once the script finishes, so does Octave. This will of course close the plot window. Remember that the plot window is also Octave, so when process end, so does the other. So the plot window does show up, but immediately closes when Octave finishes execution.

A common solution is to put a `pause` command at the end of your script. To view the plot window for a specific amount of time and close the window automatically use `pause(n)` which [pauses](https://octave.org/doc/v4.4.1/Timing-Utilities.html#XREFpause) the execution for n seconds before continuing.

A less ideal alternative, is to call the script with `octave --persistent path-to-script` to go interactive at the end.

See also, Octave's FAQ entry, [When I try plotting from a script, why am I not seeing anything?](http://wiki.octave.org/FAQ#When_I_try_plotting_from_a_script.2C_why_am_I_not_seeing_anything.3F)